# Can you get the high resolution cover photo for your page through the Graph API?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I get the cover photo for my page, for example (with Node.js):

`FB.api(pageId, { fields: cover } )`

The resulting JSON has a `source` property which is an image, but it's 720 by 405 and has JPG artifacts. When I inspect the actual Facebook page in the browser it uses a clearer 1920 by 1080 image.

How do I get that with the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the properties on the `cover` is an `id`. You can fetch this endpoint with the `images` field to return an array of sizes for that image, from 1080 height down to 130 (as of this writing).

`FB.api(coverId, { fields: images } )`

Unfortunately that's 2 requests to get 1 image - if anyone knows a better way, please let me know.